# XML to Dictionary to Instances of Custom Class

Tags: c#, xml, performance, dictionary

I am wondering if there is a more direct/elegant way than what I show below, to take data from an XML file and make instances of a custom class from it. Below is how I current do it (works, but might be a bit clumsy).

**My XML:**

```
<Skills>
  <Fire>
    <Cast>0.00</Cast>
    <ReCast>90.00</ReCast>
    <MPCost>0</MPCost>
    <Button>8</Button>
  </Fire>
  <Ice>
    <Cast>5.98</Cast>
    <ReCast>2.49</ReCast>
    <MPCost>0</MPCost>
    <Button>9</Button>
  </Ice>
</Skills>
```

**1) Loading elements from an XML into a Dictionary:**

```
//Load Skill list
var skillXElement = XDocument.Load(path + @"\Skills.xml").Root;
if (skillXElement != null)
    SkillDictionary =
        skillXElement.Elements()
            .ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName,
                e =>
                    new Skill(e.Name.LocalName, (double) e.Element("Cast"), (double) e.Element("ReCast"),
                        (int) e.Element("MPCost"), e.Element("Button").Value[0]));
```

**2) Creating references to the Skill classes based on Dictionary:**

```
class SkillInfo
{
    public Skill Fire { get; private set; }
    public Skill Ice { get; private set; }

    public SkillInfo()
    {
        Fire = Globals.Instance.SkillDictionary["Fire"];
        Ice= Globals.Instance.SkillDictionary["Ice"];
    }
}
```

**3) Finally, I access the skills through a public property as such:**

```
class Player : Character
{
    public Player()
    {
        SkillInfo = new SkillInfo();
    }

    public SkillInfo SkillInfo { get; private set; }

    private ExampleMethod()
    {
        UseSkill(SkillInfo.Fire);
    }
}
```

You might wonder why I do not just access each skill from the dictionary directly as such: `UseSkill(Globals.Instance.SkillDictionary["Fire"]);`. The reason is that each lookup in a Dictionary is fairly slow (about 500ms), despite being O(1). So, to avoid that delay each time I use a skill, I created the SkillInfo class.

Any tips or ideas on how to go from the XML to the class instances more elegantly would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Requested Additional Info Below**

- My setters are private to ensure encapsulation. It is the strictest access modifier I felt I could use. It is not a requirement other than that

Comment: Do your Fire and Ice properties need to have private setters or can they be public?..and also your SkillInfo prop in Character class?

Comment: @terrybozzio Thanks in advance for the help! All the setters in the Properties are private because I wanted to ensure encapsulation. It is basically the "strictest" access modifier I could use. It is not a requirement. I will add this info to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `MemoryStream` with a `StreamReader` to read from a file:

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<Skills>
                    <Fire>
                        <Cast>0.00</Cast>
                        <ReCast>90.00</ReCast>
                        <MPCost>0</MPCost>
                        <Button>8</Button>
                    </Fire>
                    <Ice>
                        <Cast>5.98</Cast>
                        <ReCast>2.49</ReCast>
                        <MPCost>0</MPCost>
                        <Button>9</Button>
                    </Ice>
                </Skills>";

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Skills));
        var skills = (Skills)serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        // good to go!
    }
}

public class Skill
{
    public double Cast { get; set; }
    public double ReCast { get; set; }
    public int MPCost { get; set; }
    public int Button { get; set; }
}

public class Skills
{
    public Skill Fire { get; set; }
    public Skill Ice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: True, maybe i'm putting too much weight on "take data from an XML file and make instances of a custom class from it".

Comment: Not too much weight:) OP needs to clarify if it must use and why of the private setters.

Comment: Appreciate the help here. Is the 'var skills' a List? How do you set the values of Fire and Ice? Thanks a lot

Comment: No, it's a single instance of 'Skills'. 'Fire' and 'Ice' are set by the XmlSerializer, when deserializing, because the XML elements match the property names in the class. EDIT: I renamed SkillInfo to Skills in the example xml/code.

Comment: Wow, this is quite cool. So it is absolutely critical here that the XML element names match the property names in Skill right? I will try it as soon as I get home! Thanks!!

Comment: Without attributes on the properties, yes. But you can put [XmlElement("the name of the xml element")] above a property, if you want the name of the property to be something else than the XML element name.

Comment: trydis, couple of quick questions: 1) when the Deserialization happens, does instances of Fire and Ice get created or do I have to write Fire f = new kKill(); somewhere? 2) Does the solution you provided require the Skill constructor to take 0 parameters? What if there are more than one input parameter in that constructor? 3) Will the constructor ever be run at all? Thanks!

Comment: 1) They're set by the serializer.
2) You may have other constructors, but you must have a parameterless one.
3) The parameterless one will be called by the serializer.

Comment: This was awesome, if I could give you more upvotes I would! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I just wanted to add, in case someone else comes across this, that DataContractSerializer is another option to the XmlSerializer. Basically, with the latter everything public gets serialized. With the former only stuff you specifically mark as [DataMember] will be serialized, whether it is public or private. So, you could potentially have private setters then, and more complex classes with several fields not touched by the serialization. I will go for that approach and post my final code once all is working. Currently getting some errors and trying to debug.

Comment: Yes, DataContractSerializer is the one being used in WCF.