# Completely stuck at this XML Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datacontractserializer

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am unable to deserialize my XML into class instances. Please see the two approaches I have tried (and their respective error messages), below.

**Method One:**

```
    public static SkillCollection Deserialize(string path)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Path.Combine(path, "Skills.xml"))))
        {
            SkillCollection skills = null;
            try
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SkillCollection));
                var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas(), null);
                skills = (SkillCollection)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
            }
            catch (SerializationException ex)
            {
                Globals.Instance.ApplicationLogger.Log("The object graph could not be deserialized from the binary stream because of the following error: " + ex);
            }
            return skills;
        }
    }
```

**Called like this:** `Skills = SkillCollection.Deserialize(path);`

**Error:** `XmlException was thrown: UnexpectedEndOfFile`

---

**Method Two:**

```
    public static object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File exists? " + File.Exists(xml));
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas(), null);
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(toType);
            return serializer.ReadObject(reader);
        }
    }
```

**Called like this:** `Skills = (SkillCollection) SkillCollection.Deserialize(Path.Combine(path, "Skills.xml"), typeof(SkillCollection));`

**Error 1:** `XmlException was thrown: "The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."`

**Error 2:** `SerializationException was thrown: "There was an error deserializing the object of type MagBot_FFXIV.SkillCollection. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."`

---

**My XML:**

```
<Skills>
  <Fire>
    <Cast>0.00</Cast>
    <ReCast>60.00</ReCast>
    <MPCost>0</MPCost>
    <Button>0</Button>
  </Fire>
  <Ice>
    <Cast>2.49</Cast>
    <ReCast>2.49</ReCast>
    <MPCost>9</MPCost>
    <Button>1</Button>
  </Ice>
</Skills>
```

Thanks a million for any help.

---

**UPDATE:**

I used to use LINQ2XML before, but it did not help in my case. Please see this post that I made earlier today: [XML to Dictionary to Instances of Custom Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917834/xml-to-dictionary-to-instances-of-custom-class)

---

**My final code is below. Works perfectly, hope it will help others out there.**

```
    public static object DataContractSerializer_Deserialize(string path, Type toType)
    {
        using (var sr = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            SkillCollection p = null;
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(toType);
            var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(sr, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        if (serializer.IsStartObject(reader))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(@"Found the element");
                            p = (SkillCollection)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
                        break;
                }
            }

            return p;
        }
    }
```

**Notes:**

- Keep in mind that your XML elements have to be in alpha order for DataContractSerializer to work (that does not apply to XmlSerializer)
- Also, you must include the [DataContract] attribute with Name and Namespace above both Skill and SkillCollection classes, for this to work

Comment: Offtopic but is 'button' related to the UI? It's usually a bad idea to tightly couple ui concepts and data like this.

Comment: @asawyer Nope, Button is the keyboard key that needs to be pressed to fire off the particular skill.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm talking about. More on topic, try using generic extension method helpers here: `http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Some-extension-methods-for-serializing.aspx`

Comment: It is not an issue. I simply convert the char to VkKeyScan (pInvoke) and send it off with PostMessage. That all works fine. It is when i decided to change my design from a clumsy LINQ2XML that I came accross this issue.

Comment: My only point is that by imbeding this information into your skill list you are going to make things harder for you in the future potentially. For instance an NPC that has the fire spell - why does it need a button property? How will you support people wanting a more dynamic spell bar with drag and drop or something? It might not be a big deal and certainly has nothing to do with this question. Just trying to be helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the insight asawyer, I will keep it in mind. I added another clarification link to the post, as was suggested by @L.B..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your methods have a fundamental, but easily fixed bug.

In method 1, the line:

```
new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Path.Combine(path, "Skills.xml")))
```

is wrong, because the memory stream receives the byte representation of the ***PATH*** of the file,
instead the actual contents of it.

In method2, i guess its the same error, but the parameter name "xml" is misleading. But since you're first checking for file existence with xml, i assume it also means the ***PATH*** of the file, and not its contents.

Try this instead:

```
new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Skills.xml"))))
```

Assuming the actual file contents is formatted correctly for DataContractSerializer this ***should*** work. If it doesn't, I will suggest you first Serialize a live SkillsCollection object and see what it looks like, and use that as a starting point.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I will try it right now. Could I perhaps use a StreamReader instead?